# error while sending mail using javamail

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

Here is my code for sending the mail

```
package com.markEffy.aggregator.util;
import com.sun.mail.util.MailSSLSocketFactory;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
 import javax.mail.MessagingException;
  import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
 import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

 public class EmailAgent {

        private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp.zoho.com";
        private static final String SMTP_PORT = "465";
        private static final String emailFromAddress = "support@jiffie.in";
        private static final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
        private String emailMsgTxt;
        private String emailSubjectTxt;
        private String[] sendTo = {""};

        private int msgBodyType;

        public EmailAgent (String sendToAddr, int msgType) throws Exception {
            this.sendTo[0] = new String(sendToAddr);
            this.msgBodyType = msgType;
            }
        public EmailAgent (String sendToAddr, String emailMsgTxt, String emailSubjectTxt) throws Exception {
            this.sendTo[0] = new String(sendToAddr);
            this.emailMsgTxt = emailMsgTxt;
            this.emailSubjectTxt = emailSubjectTxt;
            }

        public EmailAgent(String[] recipients, int msgType) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.sendTo = new String[recipients.length];
            for(int i=0;i<recipients.length;i++){
                this.sendTo[i]=recipients[i];
            }
            this.msgBodyType=msgType;

        }

        public  void sendMail() throws Exception {
            //System.out.println("inside send mail");

            MailSSLSocketFactory sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();

            //Check if valid arguments are passed
            if ((this.sendTo == null)) {
                System.out.println ("Invalid arguments!");
                return;
            }

            int msgType = this.msgBodyType; 
            new EmailAgent(sendTo, msgType).sendSSLMessage(sendTo, emailSubjectTxt, emailMsgTxt,
                    emailFromAddress, sf);
            System.out.println("Sucessfully Sent mail to All Users");
        }

        public void sendSSLMessage(String recipients[], String subject,
                String message, String from , MailSSLSocketFactory sf) throws MessagingException {
            boolean debug = true;
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", SMTP_PORT);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
                     {
                         protected PasswordAuthentication                   

                      getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new   
                         PasswordAuthentication("support@jiffie.in", "support@1234$");
                        }
                    });

            session.setDebug(debug);

            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
            msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);
            }
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            // Setting the Subject and Content Type
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");

            Transport.send(msg);
       }
}
```

I have added `mail.jar` and `activation.jar` in the lib folder of tomcat.I am using eclipse with tomcat 7,jre 7 and struts2.The following console error came while sending mail through Java:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.2
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
     : Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name:     {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
    DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG: Exception loading provider, THROW: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.(javax.mail.Session, javax.mail.URLName)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at javax.mail.Session.getService(Session.java:813)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:742)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:682)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:662)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:719)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:248)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.markEffy.aggregator.util.EmailAgent.sendSSLMessage(EmailAgent.java)
    at com.markEffy.aggregator.util.EmailAgent.sendMail(EmailAgent.java)
    at com.markEffy.aggregator.web.RetrievePasswordAction.sendPasswordToEmail(RetrievePasswordAction.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you at a little bit more implementation and project setup for us. It is really difficult to see what's happening just out of this stacktrace.

Comment: I have added some more details. Can u please help?

Comment: Obviously there is a version mismatch of your com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport class. Can you say, which version of mail.jar you are using?

Comment: I am using javamail-1.4.7.

Comment: Ok, here it is javamail 1.5.2, working without problems... can you look through your classpath and verify that no other mail-implementations are present, so that we can eliminate version conflicts.

Comment: Sir in tomcat/lib i have no other mail-implementations. But in aggregator/web-content/web-inf/lib i have mailapi-1.5.2. Aggregator is my project name. Can u please suggest me what should I do?

Comment: So, I have just tested your code here, works perfectly with the following two mailing artifcats com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.2 and javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.2
Always keep the api-part and the implementation-part of your mailing artifacts in sync.
So either change the mailapi-1.5.2 to mailapi-1.4.7 or update the javamail impl from 1.4.7 to 1.5.2.

Comment: Sir i checked oracle site but could not find the javamail impl 1.5.2. I am a beginner. Can u please give me the link from where can i download javamail impl 1.5.2 ? It will  be of great help.

Comment: If you are using Maven, use this: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail/1.5.2 else you can download it manually here: https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_1.5.2_Release

Comment: I've extracted also the answer from our comments thread.

Comment: You should also fix all these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have just tested your code here, works perfectly with the following two mailing artifcats com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.2 and javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.2 Always keep the api-part and the implementation-part of your mailing artifacts in sync. So either change the mailapi-1.5.2 to mailapi-1.4.7 or update the javamail impl from 1.4.7 to 1.5.2.

Comment: You don't need both com.sun.mail:javax.mail and javax.mail:javax.mail-api.  The former contains everything that's in the latter.

Comment: Yes Sir. I removed that jar.. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Read all of the answers in [multiple versions of javamail jar causing NoSuchProviderException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778327/multiple-versions-of-javamail-jar-causing-nosuchproviderexception).

You can also modify your code to set the context class loader during send to [fix this issue](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/issues/144):

```
    Thread t =  Thread.currentThread();
    ClassLoader ccl = t.getContextClassLoader();
    t.setContextClassLoader(session.getClass().getClassLoader());
    try {
        Transport.send(msg);
    } finally {
        t.setContextClassLoader(ccl);
    }
```

Comment: You save my life. Thanks!