# Java Mail: Exception when sending email

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

First time working with java mail. I'm following [this tutorial](https://smartbear.com/blog/test-and-monitor/how-to-send-email-with-embedded-images-using-java/) but I already fail at sending a basic message and I get a very strange error:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.mail.Provider: Provider com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype
```

Strange because I'm not using IMAP anywhere in my code:

```
Properties mailProps = new Properties();
mailProps.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
mailProps.put("mail.host", "smtp.mydomain.com");
mailProps.put("mail.from", "me@mydomain.com");
mailProps.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");     

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailProps);
SMTPMessage m = new SMTPMessage(session);
MimeMultipart content = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart mainPart = new MimeBodyPart();
mainPart.setText("test");
content.addBodyPart(mainPart);  
m.setContent(content);
m.setSubject("Demo message");

m.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("john@example.com"));
Transport.send(m);
```

The error happens on last line (send). I know the smtp server is correct and working.

Any advice why this happens and how I can solve it?

EDIT: obviously the addresses/hosts are changed here and I'm using real ones that work in the actual code.

Comment: You should follow this link. I had successfully used SMTP way of sending mail via same link.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_gmail_smtp_server.htm

Comment: Or also via this link, hope it helps. 
https://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-email-using-java-mail-api

Comment: @ShankarSaranSingh Your links are not for `Multipart` messages

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace. It is possible that this problem occurs if you have multiple copies of JavaMail/JakartaMail on the classpath, so please also post your dependency list (eg Maven pom.xml or Gradle build.gradle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turns out I was running into multiple issues:

1. Issue with tutorial

It uses `com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPMessage` but in my case that doesn't work but using `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage` works fine.

2. Root cause of error

Above code runs within a 3rd party eclipse based application and they seem to interfere with each other. The solution for this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29209401/972647):

```
Thread t =  Thread.currentThread();
ClassLoader ccl = t.getContextClassLoader();
t.setContextClassLoader(session.getClass().getClassLoader());
try {
    Transport.send(m);
} finally {
    t.setContextClassLoader(ccl);
}
```

Adjusting the code accordingly make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.mail.Provider: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype
```

I had a similar problem because the project is using `jakarta.mail`; and one of the dependencies brought `javax.mail` as a transitive dependency.

Excluding the the old `javax.mail` should do the trick.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

`mvn dependency:tree` views all the the dependencies and their dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for sending a multipart message with attachment:

```
String from = "from@example.com";
String to = "to@example.com";
File file = new File("/file/to/attach");

Properties mailProps = new Properties();
// put your properties here
Session session = Session.getInstance(mailProps, null);

try {
 MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
 message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from) );
 InternetAddress[] toAddress = { new InternetAddress(to) };
 message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
 message.setSubject("Demo Message");
 message.setSentDate(new Date());

 MimeBodyPart part1 = new MimeBodyPart();
 part1.setText("Test");

 MimeBodyPart part2 = new MimeBodyPart();
 part2.attachFile(file);

 Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart();
 multiPart.addBodyPart(part1);
 multiPart.addBodyPart(part2);

 message.setContent(multiPart);

 Transport.send(message);

} catch( MessagingException e ) {
  // handle the exception properly
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with libertyCore server
I add this feature in server.xml and it's work for me

```
<feature>javaMail-1.6</feature>
```