# Spring Boot, multiple errors sending email

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, gmail

I have a Spring Boot application that sends notifications via email. Recently it has randomly stopped working, and I'm not clear what the problem is.

I had a custom library to do this, but I've seen that with spring it can now be done. I have upgraded to Spring Boot 2.7.3, but I have not been able to get it to work. My configuration:

**pom.xml** (only mail dependencies):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=email
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

**Exception:**

```
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
Exception in thread "Timer-10" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/mail/Provider
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadFromParent(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:114)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.doLoadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1210)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1221)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1265)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1300)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1385)
        at javax.mail.Session.loadProviders(Session.java:964)
        at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:254)
        at javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:298)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.getSession(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:163)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.createMimeMessage(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:341)
        at my.project.package.email.EmailService.sendEmail(EmailService.java:19)
        at my.project.package.email.EmailService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8248f369.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
        at my.project.package.email.EmailService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$519bba90.sendEmail(<generated>)
        at my.project.package.cron.CheckTokenNuevo.sendEmail(CheckTokenNuevo.java:120)
        at my.project.package.cron.CheckTokenNuevo$1.run(CheckTokenNuevo.java:82)
        at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
        at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.mail.Provider
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 44 more
```

Adding this dependency to the **pom.xml**, also does not work:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And exception with **jakarta.mail** dependency:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.mail.Provider: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:589)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1237)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1265)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1300)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1385)
        at javax.mail.Session.loadProviders(Session.java:964)
        at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:254)
        at javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:298)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.getSession(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:163)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.createMimeMessage(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:341)
        at my.project.package.email.EmailService.sendEmail(EmailService.java:22)
        at my.project.package.email.EmailService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8248f369.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
        at my.project.package.email.EmailService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42519d59.sendEmail(<generated>)
        at my.project.package.cron.CheckTokenNuevo.sendEmail(CheckTokenNuevo.java:120)
        at my.project.package.cron.CheckTokenNuevo$1.run(CheckTokenNuevo.java:82)
        at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
        at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
```

I have also tried this other one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59642829/2270735

All these tests, and some more, work correctly locally from IntelliJ. It only fails in production (Docker container with openjdk11).

**NOTE:** I have changed the real name of my packages to **my.project.package**

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: The problem was in a library that included a different version of dependencies. Finally I used <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
  </dependency> and <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
   <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.1</version>
  </dependency>. Example here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email