# getting IllegalStateException when getting instance of jakarta.mail.Session object

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am new to working with jakarta.mail. I am getting the following error when creation the Session object for jakarta.mail.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not provider of jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider was found
```

The error is thrown by the FactoryFinder class find method when called by the StreamProvider class provider method, seems there are no available service providers?? Not sure what this means, new to writing email notification code.

authenticator is null, port is 25.

Comment: This answer helped me and solved the problem: [error while sending mail using javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29209401)

Answer (score 30):

It appears that you are only linking to the jakarta.mail-api library, which only contains the *API* and not the actual *implementation*. Try something like this in your Maven POM file.

Note the inclusion of the **org.eclipse.angus:jakarta.mail** dependency.

```
        <!-- Jakarta email support -->
        <!-- https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/ -->
        <!-- https://github.com/jakartaee/mail-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/angus-mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

As [Ivan B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18102385/ivan-b) suggested, I changed my dependency from

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
   <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
   <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

It helped me. Replace your jakarta dependencies to this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What helped you?

Answer (score 2):

Angus Mail 1.0 seems to be compatible with Jakarta Mail 2.1.x but does not work with Java module system.

If you want to step forward (use *jakarta.mail* instead of *javax.mail* **and** Java module system) consider using Angus Mail 2.x instead of 1.0:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.mail/jakarta.mail-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.angus/angus-mail -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
    <artifactId>angus-mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you.  What a nightmare!  The old sun mail ran on windows, but not on Linux and the error message is horrible.  Angus ran perfectly.  It it time to get rid of old Sun implementations!  Want to upvote this answer a lot more.

Answer (score -2):

Just a quick hint on this.
Make sure you are running the `jakarta.mail` related methods in a thread safe environment